Is there a way to align a title to the right while keeping a small space between the title name and the right text margin?
I am writing my master's dissertion and I have been trying to change the format of the chapters' titles using the package titlesec.
My goal is to have the chapters' title and label right-aligned. Despite managing to do so, I'd like to have a small gap between the chapter title and the right margin.
So far I tried to:

Use \hspace{} in conjuction with \hfill and \raggedleft; include the title in a \makebox[\textwidth][r] and use \hspace{} to pull the box slightly to the left;
include the title in a \makebox[\textwidth][r] and use \hspace{} to pull the box slightly to the left.

However, these attempts didn't produce the desired output. How can I achieve this small blank space while keeping the title and label aligned to the right?
Thank you in advance!
Below, you may find my preamble and a small example of the code I am using:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}

% Margins and spacing
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

% Font -- Times New Roman
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

% Headers and footnotes
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Chapter titles costumization
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Chapters before main body
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] %command and shape
{\normalfont\Huge} % Format
{} % Label (there are no labels for this part, ie., \chapter*{})
{3pt} % Sep between label and title
{\titlerule\vspace{8pt}\Huge\hspace{5pt}} % Style
[\vspace{1.5pt}\titlerule] % Line below title

% Chapters main body
\newcommand{\MainBodyChapterStyle}{
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display] %command and shape
    {\normalfont\Huge} % Title format
    {\vspace{-0.5cm}\hfill\fontfamily{qbk}\fontsize{85}{70}\selectfont\thechapter} % Label format
    {3pt} % Sep between label and title
    {\titlerule\vspace{8pt}\raggedleft\hspace{-5pt}} % Style
    [\vspace{1.5pt}\titlerule] % Line below title
}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter*{Abstract}
This work is about something pretty interesting


\MainBodyChapterStyle

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Methodologies}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}


I guess you also want the unnumbered chapter titles to be “almost” flush right.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}

% Margins and spacing
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}

% Font -- Times New Roman
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

% Chapter titles costumization
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text


% Headers and footnotes
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%%% SETTINGS

% pagestyle
\pagestyle{fancy}
% fill in the required instructions


% Chapters before main body
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display] %command and shape
  {\normalfont\Huge\filleft} % Format
  {} % Label (there are no labels for this part, ie., \chapter*{})
  {0pt} % Sep between label and title
  {\snwtitle}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display] %command and shape
  {\normalfont\Huge\filleft} % Title format
  {\fontfamily{qbk}\fontsize{85}{0}\selectfont\thechapter\hspace*{1pc}} % Label format
  {6pt} % Sep between label and title
  {\snwtitle}

\newcommand{\snwtitle}[1]{%
  \hrule
  \vspace{8pt}
  \strut#1\hspace*{1pc}%
  \hrule
}

% interline space
\linespread{1.15}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter*{Abstract}
This work is about something pretty interesting


\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Methodologies}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}



A few notes:

\linespread{1.15} is the command of choice, rather than redefining \baselinestretch.

There's no need to call for renewing the chapter styles.

The last argument to \titleformat may end with a command that expects an argument and will be passed the title as such.

I set headheight=13.6pt per the recommendation by fancyhdr.


